# jquery how to use decimal numbers in if checkup

Tags: jquery, numbers, decimal

What is correct way to use decimal number with two decimal places in if checkup in jquery?

I have writted this way

```
$(".entered").change(function(){
 if(parseInt(this.value) > 39617756.85){
    alert('greater');
 } 
})
```

but it seems that it doeasn work: http://jsfiddle.net/dzorz/rremm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using parseFloat, like this:

```
$(".entered").change(function(){
 if(parseFloat(this.value) > 39617756.85){
    alert('greater');
 } 
})
```

Answer (score 2):

user parseFloat instead of parseInt

```
parseFloat(this.value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `parseFloat` for floating point precision:

```
$(".entered").change(function(){
    if (parseFloat(this.value) > 39617756.85) {
        alert('greater');
    } 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".entered").change(function(){
   if(parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2) > 39617756.85){
      alert('greater');
   } 
})
```

worked for me